# Python how to only remove the first duplicated character in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a string 'cbbcc',I want to remove 1 of the characters in each round, from left to right, and return the remaining character, like this:

```
first round:  bbcc
second round: cbcc
third round:  cbbc
Forth round:  cbbc
```

But if I use the following code:

```
    for i in s:
        old_s=s
        s=s.replace(i,'')
        print(s)
        s=old_s
```

The output will be:

```
bb
ccc
ccc
bb
bb
```

Is there anyway I can make the output like:

```
bbcc
cbcc
cbbc
cbbc
```

In real business the string can be very very long.

Comment: Could you be more clear on what you're trying to accomplish here?  This is not a good explanation: `I have a string 'aba',in a for loop ,I want to remove 1 of the characters in each round, and return the left character, like this`

Comment: Which one of the characters are you trying to remove each round?  How are you determining the 'left' character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could slice the string, instead of replacing:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(f"{s[:i]}{s[i+1:]}")
```

Output:

```
ba
aa
ab
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
s = 'aba'

for i in range(len(s)):
    new_s = s.replace(s[i], "", 1)
    print(new_s)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but if s='cbbcc',your code will not work.

Comment: it work, but if you also want to remove duplicate char the code is not work